# How to add an interactive heatmap to a PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, heatmap, heatmaply

I have created a heatmap in R and heatmaply. I need to add this heatmap to a paper I am publishing. The heatmap is very big and heatmaply's zoom is very useful. Is it possible to add this heatmap - it becomes a .html file when saved - to a PDF? 
Is there any method to add an interactive heatmap another than a hyperlink?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is - no. Adding *interactive* graphics (like heatmaply) to a PDF file is not possible. My best advice is to go for something that supports HTML.

You can, however, add a static image to a PDF file by outputting the heatmap from heatmaply by following the documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmaply/heatmaply.pdf (search for "static").

Comment: As in the manual entry for the `file` argument: "name of the file(s) into which to save the heatmaply output. Should be a character vector of strings ending with ".html" for a dynamic output, or ".png", ".jpeg",
".pdf" for a static output.".